# Software center problems after upgrade to 13.04

Tags: 13.04, software-center

When I try to start software-center I get this:

```
2013-07-28 17:05:22,922 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-07-28 17:05:26,357 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-07-28 17:05:26,375 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2013-07-28 17:05:26,414 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2013-07-28 17:05:26,414 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration

(software-center:26001): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/entrio/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
2013-07-28 17:05:27,386 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
```

It worked in the previous version 12.10, but it always crashes at start now. I know that there are work arounds (like Synaptic).

I've already tried [Problem in upgrading and opening software center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245763/problem-in-upgrading-and-opening-software-center)

OK. solved the problem above, but now I get:

```
2013-07-28 18:10:47,442 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-07-28 18:10:47,740 - softwarecenter.region - WARNING - failed to use geoclue: 'org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Error.notAvailable: Geoclue master client has no usable Address providers'
2013-07-28 18:10:48,058 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-07-28 18:10:48,062 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2013-07-28 18:10:48,069 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2013-07-28 18:10:48,069 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2013-07-28 18:10:48,130 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

BWT, I also get segmentation fault (core dumped) error messages when I try to start evolution.

I purged it and re-installed. Got these messages:

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main python-oneconf all 0.3.3 [21.8 kB]

Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main software-center all 5.6.0-0ubuntu2 [443 kB]

Fetched 465 kB in 4s (112 kB/s)           

Selecting previously unselected package python-oneconf.

(Reading database ... 420056 files and directories currently installed.)

Unpacking python-oneconf (from .../python-oneconf_0.3.3_all.deb) ...

Selecting previously unselected package software-center.

Unpacking software-center (from .../software-center_5.6.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb) ...

Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...

Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...

Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...

Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...

Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...

Processing triggers for man-db ...

Setting up python-oneconf (0.3.3) ...

Setting up software-center (5.6.0-0ubuntu2) ...

Updating software catalog...this may take a moment.

INFO:softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache:aptcache.open()

WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/sonic-
visualiser:x-sonicvisualiser.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application 
associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please 
consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application

WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/sonic-
visualiser:x-sonicvisualiser-layer.desktop' could not be read correctly. The 
application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. 
Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that 
application

WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop
/workrave:workrave.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated 
with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising 
a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application

Software catalog update was successful.
```

Comment: Have you been using Terminal with `sudo`? It looks like the ownership of some of the files have been changed and can not be read.

Comment: Yep, how can I repair that?

Comment: Besides that: other applications are not starting after this upgrade to 13.04: evolution, ubuntu tweak, unity tweak.

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is reporting that `The owner of /home/entrio/.config/ibus/bus is not root!` I think that most, if not all the files stored in /home/entrio/ should be owned by you so, right click on the hidden file .config and select the properties tab. if this is set to root, you have somehow changed this ownership as it should be owned by **Me** group **entrio**.

To change these back, you need to start nautilus from terminal with `sudo nautilus` navigate to the `/home/entrio/.config` file and change the owner by right clicking on ibus selecting properties and then clicking the permissions tab. Change the owner to you and the group to you. **This could be just the start if you have managed to alter permissions elswhere!**

/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc could also have been changed. the ownership for the files in /usr/share/ should be **root** and group should be **root**

If other programmes are not starting, it may be easier to backup/copy important files to a different drive and reinstalling or try to fix the information by running a re-installation from your LiveCD.

Comment: I am sure this is a problem with 13.04, and not about me messing around too much.

Comment: I agree, but find out what the permissions are, then we can have a go at fixing it. No blame inferred :)

Comment: The permissions were wrong, but now there is no error message related to ibus/bus' owner, but it's still not starting. I have post the new error messages in my post above.